# How do I get html tag value (div) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have implemented this function (libphonenumber javascript )in a website 
http://www.phoneformat.com/

How do i get the value returned by this html tag. Whether Yes or No

```
< DIV id="phone_valid" class="popup-value"></DIV>'
```

I have tried this

```
function checkSubmit(){
var country=$("#phone_valid").val();
if(country=="No")
{
    alert("Not a valid number");
    return false;
}
```

So far no luck

Comment: For getting contents of a `div` use either `innerHTML` or `textContent` and not `val`. In jQuery the equivalents would be `html()` or `text()`.

Comment: @Harry: he's using jquery !

Comment: What does `.val()` return ?, if it returns `undefined` maybe you need to use `.html()` or `.text()`

Comment: @SnakeEyes: Yup, late realization on my part, but already updated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`.

Use

```
$("#phone_valid").text();
```

to get DIV text content or

```
$("#phone_valid").html();
```

if you want markup.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do this:

```
$("#phone_valid").html();
```

or

```
$("#phone_valid").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

.val() is for form elements. You should use .text() or .html() to get the value from a `DIV`.

**HTML**

```
<DIV id="phone_valid" class="popup-value"></DIV>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function checkSubmit(){
    var country=$("#phone_valid").html();
    if(country=="No")
    {
        alert("Not a valid number");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

First, no space between `<` and `div` (saw here: `< DIV id="phone_valid" class="popup-value"></DIV>'` )

Second:

```
function checkSubmit(){
var country=$("#phone_valid").text(); // it is a div not input to get val().
if(country=="No")
{
    alert("Not a valid number");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
document.getElementById("phone_valid").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JavaScript you can use `document.getElementById` to get a specific node using ID:

```
var node = document.getElementById('phone_valid');
```

And then to get the text from that node you will need to use:

```
var text = node.innerText || node.textContent;
```

The jQuery `.val()` method is used on form fields like `input`, `textarea`, `select`...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to include HTML comments then consider using  [contents() method](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

`$('#mydiv').contents()`

Other wise `html()` method or even `text()` will be what you are looking for because `val()` purpose is for form elements ;)