# Get the value of a tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, tags

I would like to get the value of a tag after clicking on it. I just use javascript and no jquery.
Here's my html :

```
<div class="touche 1">
   <h1>1</h1>
</div>
<div class="touche 2">
   <h1>2</h1>
</div>
<div class="touche 3">
   <h1>3</h1>
</div>
```

I need the values 1,2,3, etc... into a variable. The div's work like a calculator button !

Thanks !

Comment: And where exactly did you get stuck, when you attempted to solve this yourself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451144/how-do-i-get-html-tag-value-div-in-javascript

Comment: I just tried function $id(id) { return document.getElementById(id);}

Comment: And what was the error you got?

Comment: I got "undefined" when I try to use the variable and no errors on the log

Comment: You got that because there are no elements with `id`

Comment: I do have id, I just didn't write them in the example

Comment: I use $id(id).value and it returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code

```js
function getval(thisa)
{
  alert(thisa.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div class="touche 1">
   <h1 onclick="getval(this)">1</h1>
</div>
<div class="touche 2">
   <h1 onclick="getval(this)">2</h1>
</div>
<div class="touche 3">
   <h1 onclick="getval(this)">3</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok! I used thisa.childNodes[0].innerHTML and it works!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly access the `<h1>` tags, you can use [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName), which returns a collection of HTMLElements. You can iterate over them an attach a click event handler.

Inside the event handler, you can use it's [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) property for getting the text (*read as value*) as follows:

```js
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
    for(var i=0;i<elms.length;i++){
      elms[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
        console.log(this.textContent);
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="touche 1">
   <h1>1</h1>
</div>
<div class="touche 2">
   <h1>2</h1>
</div>
<div class="touche 3">
   <h1>3</h1>
</div>
```

---

If you want to bind the listener for the `<div>`'s, You can use [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) or [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) for accessing the elements, loop through them and attach click event listener.

Inside the event handler, you can use the [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) property to access the `<h1>` get it's value as mentioned above.

```js
var elms = document.getElementsByClassName("touche");
for(var i=0;i<elms.length;i++){
  elms[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log(this.children[0].textContent);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="touche 1">
   <h1>1</h1>
</div>
<div class="touche 2">
   <h1>2</h1>
</div>
<div class="touche 3">
   <h1>3</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following js to do this. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Arindamnayak/e5tzktet/)

```
var controls = document.getElementsByClassName("touche");
for(var i = 0;i<controls.length;i++)
{
    controls[i].onclick = function() {
        console.log(this.childNodes[1].innerText);

        alert(this.childNodes[1].innerText);
    };
}
```